# Как при повторном нажатии запустить повторно скрипт?

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JS совсем недавно (пару недель) по скаченному курсу, и там такое задание:

Цель задания

•   Получить практику работы с DOM-элементами и событиями.

•   Научиться выполнять код с заданной периодичностью.

Задание

Создайте HTML-страницу с полем для ввода числа, кнопкой и div-элементом с числом 0. В поле для ввода должно вводиться число с количеством секунд, а кнопка должна запускать таймер. При запуске таймера число в div-элементе должно замениться на введённое в поле. Затем каждую секунду оно должно уменьшаться на единицу до тех пор, пока не дойдёт до 0. При этом таймер должен корректно работать, если во время его работы пользователь запускает его заново.

Проверка результата

При запуске таймера он корректно работает, уменьшая число каждую секунду. Если нажать на кнопку запуска таймера ещё раз, предыдущий интервал остановится и таймер начнёт свою работу заново. Таймер заканчивает работу сразу при достижении 0.

Критерии оценки

Код должен быть простым и понятным, без ненужных усложнений и лишних сущностей.
В setInterval первым параметром передаётся функция (НЕ строка с кодом).

Рекомендации к выполнению

В JavaScript есть специальный механизм, позволяющий запускать произвольную функцию с заданным интервалом. Для этого есть 2 функции:

•   setInterval для запуска таймера. Подробнее: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval. Важно! Хоть функция и позволяет это делать, никогда не передавайте первым параметром строку с кодом! Только функцию. Код должен быть кодом, а не строкой - так его гораздо проще контролировать.

•   clearInterval для остановки таймер. Подробнее: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval. Не бойтесь вызывать clearInterval даже если не уверены, что таймер запущен. В таком случае не будет ошибки, просто ничего не произойдёт.

У меня следующая проблема:

При нажатии на кнопку повторно скрипт не запускается заново.

При нажатии на кнопку повторно цифры начинают ускоренно уменьшаться. Все таки заново запускается???

При нажатии на кнопку, когда в input ничего не введено - скрипт запускается и в консоле -1. а потом еще раз нажмешь -2. Это вроде и не проблема, но говорит мне о том, что возможно я что-то не так сделал.

мой JS код до которого дошел:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let inputNumber1 = document.getElementById('input');
    let buttonN = document.getElementById('button');
    let divN = document.getElementById('div');
    let inputCoff = 0;


    function startTimer() {
        nIntervId = setInterval(onClick, 1000);
    };



    function onClick() {
    
       divN.textContent = inputNumber1.value - inputCoff;
       inputCoff += 1;
       console.log(divN.textContent)

       if (divN.textContent <= 0) {
           divN.textContent = 0;
           clearInterval(nIntervId);
       }
       
    };

    buttonN.addEventListener('click', startTimer);
});
```

мой HTML кодик:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script defer src="/home-task/7/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="input" value="">
    <button id="button">Запуск таймера</button>
    <div id="div">0</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

всем сердешко <3

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let inputNumber1 = document.getElementById('input');
  let buttonN = document.getElementById('button');
  let divN = document.getElementById('div');
  let inputCoff = 0;

  function startTimer() {
    nIntervId = setInterval(onClick, 1000);
  };

  function onClick() {
    divN.textContent = inputNumber1.value - inputCoff;
    inputCoff += 1;
    console.log(divN.textContent)

    if (divN.textContent <= 0) {
      divN.textContent = 0;
      clearInterval(nIntervId);
    }

  };

  buttonN.addEventListener('click', startTimer);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script defer src="/home-task/7/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="input" value="">
  <button id="button">Запуск таймера</button>
  <div id="div">0</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let input = document.getElementById('input');
  let button = document.getElementById('button');
  let div = document.getElementById('div');
  let current = 0;
  let timer;

  function startTimer() {
    div.textContent = --current;
    if (current <= 0)
      timer = clearInterval(timer);
  }

  function onClick() {
    timer = clearInterval(timer);
    
    current = +input.value;
    if (current) {
      div.textContent = current;
      timer = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
    }
  }

  button.addEventListener('click', onClick);
});
```

```html
<input id="input" value="10">
<button id="button">Запуск таймера</button>
<div id="div">0</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let time = document.querySelector('.time');
    let btnStart = document.querySelector('.start');
    let score = document.querySelector('.timer');
    let timer;

    function startTimer() {
      score.textContent -= 1;
      if (score.textContent <= 0) {
        timer = clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }

    function clickOn() {
      timer = clearInterval(timer);

      if (time.value > 0) {
        score.textContent = time.value;
        timer = setInterval(startTimer, 1000)
      } else {timer = clearInterval(timer)}
    }

    btnStart.addEventListener('click', clickOn);
}) // end DOM
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>7.6 task 1</title>
    <script src="./7.6.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="containet" style="text-align: center; align-items: center; max-width: 300px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 15px; background-color: wheat; box-sizing: border-box;">
        <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: max-content; margin-bottom: 20px; box-sizing: border-box;">
            <input class="time" type="number" placeholder="0" style=" max-width: 75px; margin-right: 10px; padding: 5px 10px; background-color: aliceblue; border: 1px solid black; box-sizing: border-box;">
            <button class="start" style="padding: 5px 10px; background-color: aliceblue; border: 1px solid black; box-sizing: border-box;">Start</button>
        </div>
        <div class="timer" style="width: max-content; margin: 0 auto; padding: 5px 15px; background-color: aliceblue; border: 1px solid black; box-sizing: border-box;">0</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Привет тоже начал изучать и делать получилось как то так)